# Animation not returning to original

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a menu which looks like this:

[image]

When i scroll down i want the logo to disappear. I tried to achieve that with the scroll function in jquery.

The jQuery code looks like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $('.logo').animate({marginTop: -500, width:5, padding:0},'fast');
    $('.navigation').css('background-color','rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.59)');
  } else {
    $('.logo').animate({marginTop: 0, width:5, padding:0},'fast');
    $('.navigation').css('background-color','rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.59)');
  }
})
```

I also want that when i go back to top it returns to my original value. I tried to achieve this with the else statement, see code above.

The first part is achieved succesfully but something goes wrong in the else part. When i scroll back up this is the immage i get:

[image]

My entire code including html and css:

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!--general stuff --> 
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- custom css-->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--custom css-->
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--slider-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slider/slick/slick.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slider/slick/slick-theme.css"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="navigation">  
      <ul>
          <li><a>Home</a></li>
          <li><a>About me</a></li>
          <li class= 'logo'><img src="https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/disp/ff8f6032715585.569069e7a9b6c.png"></li>
          <li><a>Home</a></li>
          <li><a>About me</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="slider">
      <div class="slide"><img src="https://dailypost.files.wordpress.com/2016/06/city.jpeg?w=1200"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="http://www.wheretowillie.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Glow-of-the-Windy-City-2.jpg"></div>
    </div>

    <p style = "overflow:hidden;">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus gravida laoreet libero, ac ornare lorem ultrices non. Cras viverra elit nisl, in facilisis ligula sagittis maximus. Nam porta libero quis sapien dignissim tristique. Duis semper felis eu lorem fringilla dignissim. Etiam cursus felis a lobortis posuere. Pellentesque eu tincidunt velit. Maecenas eget aliquet ipsum, id tempor ex. Quisque bibendum odio vel odio volutpat commodo. Sed vitae tellus nulla. Etiam elementum erat vitae eros euismod, et ultrices velit aliquam. Sed elementum dictum tortor vitae fermentum. Duis rhoncus felis turpis, non facilisis felis mattis a. Maecenas dolor nisi, venenatis sit amet sodales ornare, varius ac orci. Praesent pellentesque imperdiet sollicitudin. Aenean pellentesque velit tortor, porttitor fringilla justo dictum nec.

Vestibulum in tincidunt odio. Nam pharetra urna eget tellus luctus tincidunt. Cras posuere, lacus id sodales facilisis, libero dui interdum odio, et molestie augue erat at leo. Etiam pretium aliquet justo. Morbi id metus a diam ultricies dapibus. Aenean a ante nec eros blandit dignissim. Morbi purus ante, eleifend non viverra ultricies, auctor dignissim mauris. Aliquam rutrum risus nibh, eget eleifend enim aliquam nec. Integer nec eleifend diam, eget cursus leo. In non finibus nulla, a cursus diam. Mauris bibendum condimentum suscipit.

Nam quis enim felis. Phasellus molestie quam at velit aliquet euismod. Curabitur ac justo quis leo viverra ultrices. Vestibulum sit amet purus id sem rutrum vehicula et sed ante. Maecenas finibus, augue ut faucibus hendrerit, leo nisi tristique purus, sed congue ante sapien in arcu. Phasellus dignissim turpis ex, id porta ipsum pellentesque ac. Mauris ac sapien hendrerit, vestibulum risus id, gravida ligula. Proin laoreet aliquet ante, id viverra felis tincidunt euismod. Duis eu urna et massa convallis ultricies. Aenean consectetur lectus eu ipsum vestibulum, eget imperdiet tellus faucibus. Pellentesque tincidunt nunc tincidunt ex tincidunt, quis hendrerit lorem lobortis. Vivamus congue, nibh sit amet consectetur ornare, eros turpis sodales sem, in consequat dui dolor ac eros.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In id efficitur elit. Donec posuere varius metus at molestie. Morbi sit amet velit dui. Integer eget iaculis nibh. Vivamus diam purus, posuere a leo ultricies, tempus tempor lacus. Proin vestibulum eros a sapien aliquam mollis sit amet at lacus. Donec at congue risus, non ullamcorper mi. Integer finibus ligula porttitor, eleifend eros eget, luctus libero. Nulla erat odio, ultrices eget velit vitae, rhoncus tristique dolor. In nulla mi, laoreet sit amet libero sed, auctor efficitur metus. Sed gravida lorem sed sagittis sagittis. Etiam et ante vehicula lectus dictum consequat. Duis porttitor dolor sed libero mattis, sed malesuada nisl facilisis.

Integer pretium mi eu sagittis laoreet. Mauris euismod ac odio sed viverra. Curabitur vitae nulla in ex ultrices mollis at imperdiet massa. Donec venenatis, nisl non convallis cursus, augue leo consequat massa, a volutpat enim urna vel nibh. Aenean mattis fringilla lectus, tristique commodo ante convallis ac. Ut dui magna, dapibus eget elit eget, sodales iaculis turpis. Ut posuere tincidunt felis, id pretium nisi blandit mattis. Sed sed nisi id quam vestibulum aliquam vitae lobortis odio. Praesent porttitor leo id lacus posuere tristique. Sed sodales ultricies dapibus. Nam at molestie massa.
    </p>

    <!--jQuery-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap js -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!--slick slider-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="slider/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <!-- custom js -->
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Css:

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  position: relative;
}

/*Navigation section*/

.navigation {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 25px 0;
  background: transparent;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;

}
.navigation ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.navigation ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left:20px;
  padding-right:20px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.navigation ul li a {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:white;
}

.navigation li img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 180px;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-left:50px;
  margin-right:50px;
}
/*The slider*/

.slick-slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh!important;
}
.slide img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

A live version is to be found on this [website](http://u512656.gluweb.nl/mop/)

remember the first part is doing what i want (when u scroll down) but it needs to return to its original state when im back on top and this doesnt happen. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not resetting your width (or your padding)

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $('.logo').animate({marginTop: -500, width:5px, padding:0},'fast');
    $('.navigation').css('background-color','rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.59)');
  } else {
    $('.logo').animate({marginTop: 0, width:200px, padding:0},'fast');
    $('.navigation').css('background-color','rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.59)');
  }
})
```

A better way would be to animate the scale property as width/padding does not animate well - beyond the scope of your question though.

And you should also have the 'px' in there really...

Comment: No because giving it px gives me an error unexpected identifier

Comment: also the width 200 is still not to the original position see screenshot http://prntscr.com/earx6c

Comment: you need to do the same for padding also

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `width:5`  in the script: It remains at width 5px when you scroll back up (you also have it in the `else` clause), so it's practically hidden. Just reset it to the initial value in the else clause.

Comment: How can i find out what the initial value is?

Comment: nvm its the width of the image haha